# Ace editor modifies autocomplete list

Tags: ace-editor

I'm trying to filter a possible list of results for ace autocomplete. I want to match a substring of a prefix with my list of keywords.
Example - `keylist = ['cat','ciat'], prefix = ['ca']`. I want to see only cat.
Ace by default return both the words.

I have tried using "insertmatch" but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Once your autocompleted list is loaded, filter the elements in your **keylist** with the filter function.

```
var prefix = ca //keep updating the prefix value here
var matched_keylist = keylist.filter(function (v) {return /prefix/.test(v)});
```

The **matched_keylist** should contain string 'cat'

Comment: Consider this example - keylist = ['map', 'monitor']
prefix = 'm' --- autocomplete list shows   ['map', 'monitor'].
prefix = 'mo' -- autocomplete list shows ['monitor'].
prefix = 'moo' -- autocomplete list shows ['moonitor']. Where in there is no such word.

Comment: Is your autocomplete showing list when the there are no values in keylist?

Comment: yes, it does. It does not show empty list in such cases.

Comment: `var regex = new RegExp(prefix, 'g');  
filtered_list = keylist.filter(function(data) {  
                              return regex.test(data);  
                            });  
 callback(null, filtered_list.map(function(data) {  
                return {  
                  caption: data,  
                  value: data,  
                  meta: ''  
                }  
}));`

Comment: When you have ['map', 'monitor'] and your prefix is 'moo' you are getting an empty string in matched_keylist right?

Comment: I'm just getting an empty array with no values.

Comment: Yes, as there are no matching values with the substring you should not be getting any values right?

Comment: Yes. But in the editor in can see autcomplete dropdown with values ['moonitor']

Comment: Does your autocomplete list contain only 2 values in the array ie ['map', 'monitor]?

Comment: Yes, only two values.

Comment: Then there might be a problem with your regex. Why don't you try once without the regex and directly use the way I provided in the answer

Comment: Can't do that as my prefix is a variable. please check http://plnkr.co/edit/wTiRiHoqUWEphPJUBJxi?p=preview

Comment: Can you try to match this code https://js.do/harshapps/matchsubstringsaceexample this one works fine for me. Just try to embed into your code

Comment: The list is empty as expected, but ace editor is showing it as 'moonitor'. Try out in the link provided.